# check if it happens in 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, date

Imagine we're giving users the ability to send emails using our website, but we want to limit them to not send more than 30 emails per day(24 hours).

So, by sending each email we're gonna insert a record into our table, then while he/she wants to send another one, we check if he has sent more than 30 emails during 24 hours or not.

How we could check this with PHP?

we query db, we got 20 records for this user, the date of records are:

```
2012-08-14 13:10:58
2012-08-14 12:45:47
2012-08-14 16:32:18
2012-08-14 19:10:40
...
...
...
```

How we could achieve such rule?

Thanks

Comment: a day and 24 hours have **not** the same meaning, do you mean a calendar interval or a time interval? You may limit on a per day basis (from 00:00 to 23:59) or during a 24 hours interval (from Day A on 08:30AM to Day B on 08:30AM). The resulting algorithm will not be the same.

Comment: I need it to be based by 24 hours time interval, not a calendar day interval. ty

Comment: @BorisGuéry, is this gonna gives me what I want? "date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)"? or it's giving the 24 hours calendar interval? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check it in PHP, use a simple query like this to get the answer out of he database right off the bat.

```
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    yourTableName 
where 
    dateCol>date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
    and userID=...
```

This will give you the count.

Edit: As Boris points out, this will count per day, you could change it to check for the last 24 hour period like this:

```
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    yourTableName 
where 
    dateCol>date_sub(now(), interval 24 hour) 
    and userID=...
```

Edit 2: After checking this, Riad correcly points out, these two do in fact return the same value. The `1 day` is treated as exactly 1 day, not a calendar date. If the date column has a datetime of '2012-08-13: 13:00:00' a `date_sub( dateCol, interval 1 day)` will return '2012-08-12: 13:00:00'.

Comment: It seems it needed a 'INTERVAL' before '24 hour' ==> SELECT COUNT( id )
FROM TABLE
WHERE dateCol > date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 24 hour)

Comment: @behz4d Yes, you are right, sorry I always forget to add it in, then remember when I get the syntax error. +1 and edited now.

Comment: BTW, `date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) == date_sub(now(), interval 24 hour) `, try `select date_sub(now(), interval 24 hour), date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);`

Comment: @RiaD, you're saying this query checks the calendar 24 hours interval and not in 24 hours? would you please explain more? BorisGuéry also mentioned such issue in the first comment of my post, thanks

Comment: @behz4d No, he is saying that they will give the same result. The datetime returned will be the same no matter which option you use.

Comment: @benz4d, no, it works with 24 hour intervals [this time yesterday, now], but there two absolutly same code in the answer, pointed as different